# saving mail body from outlook

Tags: com, outlook, atl

I'm new to COM/ATL development . I've build a COM add-in for Outlook 2010, using this tutorial as main source of information. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941475%28v=office.14%29.aspx.

When I click a button(that I specifically asign) , I want to save the body of emails(all the mails from inbox) in a text file . Can somebody give me an ideea how do i that? Any code snippet would be great.

Thanks in advance.

My function looks like this :
    STDMETHOD(ButtonClicked)( IDispatch * RibbonControl)
    {

```
    _ApplicationPtr pApp;
    _NameSpacePtr pNamespace;
    pApp->GetNamespace(L"MAPI");
    MAPIFolderPtr InboxFolder = pNamespace->GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
    _ItemsPtr mails = InboxFolder->Items;
    const long count = mails->GetCount();

    for(long i=1;i<=count;i++)
    {
        //?
    }
    return S_OK;


}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MailItemPtr msg = mails.Items(i);
msg.SaveAs("c:\\myfile.txt", olTxt);
```

Keep in mind that you can have objects other than MailItem in the Inbox (report items, meetings invitations, etc.), so you might want to declare the object that you retrieve from mails.Items(I) as `IDispatch` and explicitly call `QueryInterface()` to retrieve MailItem.